# Rotation around non orthogonal axis

Tags: rotations

I am trying to wrap my head around some problem. How to calculate correct angle of rotation, when one of the rotation axis isnt orthogonal to machining plane.

Lets imagine that we put a box on the table c axis, and want to machine its right/left side.

On orthogonal kinematics, i would simply rotate B axis to B-90 or B90

[Orthogonal kinematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CBzL.png)

So rotation of the object, equals rotations of machine axes.

In the image below, B axis is rotating at plane shifted by 45 degree.
So when i want to machine left/right side of the box, i would have to rotate both B and C axis ( by C90/C270 and B180)

[Nutated B axis in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBxjM.png)

How to find this real B and C angle? (how to take into account that B axis of rotation is angled at 45 degree and find those 2 angles).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Elaborated a little bit more